# c# download button url error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Below is the code for download a file. My url works(able to download) however my url2 didn't work(unable to download). What is the error that i did for url2? any problems with my relative path?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url =@"C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\backup fyp\10-18-2011\WebSite5\123.txt";
    string url2 = @"~\123.txt";
    FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(url);

    if (finfo.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + finfo.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", finfo.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.WriteFile(finfo.FullName);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get a 404 error? do you get the wrong file? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: for the first url,my file able to download,which is 123.txt, for url2,my file cannot be found=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~\123.txt` is a virtual path. You need to use it like this:

```
string url2 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\123.txt");
```